# Weird result comparing the errorformula with the actual error using the trapezoid method

Tags: numerical-integration

The graph I got using the code in the link is VERY peculiar to say the least. I have no idea what's causing it.

https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1840718?p_p_auth=PKMDl2TX

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that. I wrote another method than that one too, but it didn't work either. Didn't even show a graph, but got the right value. Was probably due to how I let Mathematica calculate it.

Comment: Sorry, I was still writing my reply when it posted. I tried the code you posted, but that gave the exact same graph, unfortunately. It works with other functions though (I tried Exp[Cos[x-42]]-Log[2/x^4]).